# Prove that the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is a flat $R$-module.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, free-modules, flatness

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Prove that the polynomial ring $R[x]$ in the indeterminate $x$ over the commutative ring $R$ is a flat $R$-module.

**My thoughts:**

We know by corollary 42 in D&F, third edition, that free modules are flat. I know that any free module has a basis but is the converse true? Is any module that had a basis is a free module. Here is my proof depending on that the converse is true (**if not please tell me the correct solution**):

Given a commutative ring $R,$ the polynomial ring $R[x]$ is a free $R$-module because for instance, every element in $R[x]$ can be written as $a_0 + a_1 x + \cdots + a_n x^n$ for some non-negative integer $n$ and some elements $a_i$ in $R,$ hence the linearly independent elements $1, x, x^2, \dots$ generate $R[x]$ over $R.$

Comment: What is your definition of a free module? Having a basis is one of the equivalent definitions, but I assume it's not the one you use.

Comment: My definition is the one on pg. 354 of dummit & Foote. It says an R module F is said to be free on the subset A of F if for every nonzero element $x \in F,$ there exist unique nonzero elements $r_1, \dots, r_n$ of R ..... @Mark I think you meant to say that the reverse direction works also, am I correct?

Comment: Yes, so it's the same thing. As I see, they even write that the set $A$ is called a basis. That's the definition of a basis, so you have nothing to prove here. By definition, a module is free if it has a basis.

Comment: @Mark thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @Secretly Maybe you can answer your own question and avoid abandoning this thing here forever without an answer?